# Xcode 8 App installation failed, unknown error occured

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

[image: Error message[1]]

The following error occurred when I tried to run a project on my iOS device. Running it on a simulator works fine.

The other weird thing is that I am able to run my other projects on my device, only this particular project that is giving me this error.

I tried all the solutions I'm able to find:

1. Cleaning the project, deleting derived data
2. Restarting Xcode, my Mac, and my iOS device
3. Deselect 'Automatically manage signing' in the testing Target.
4. I couldn't delete the app from my device and re-install it because it wasn't installed on my device before.

Any help would mean alot to me! I am using Xcode 8.1 with Swift 3.0, running on a iOS 10.1.1 device.

Comment: Chan Jing, did you create certificates and provisioning profile with your device UIDI?

Comment: @RajJoshi Hi, I'm using the free developer account, for signing and provisioning profile, XCode did that automatically for me. My other project is able to run on my device, just curious why this one could not.

Answer (score 20):

1. Close your Xcode completely from currently running on Dock
2. Unplug your iDevices cable at your Mac and plug again.
3. Open Xcode Again.
4. Clean,Build and Wait for indexing the device
5. Delete the previous app you install on your iDevice
6. Then install

> *If you have free Developer ID, make sure you got the Internet access*
>   *right on your iDevices.*

Else,

1. Check your provision profile or certificates of your app that it's still available or not [Expire or not].
2. If expired, please create again.
3. Install those latest provision profile at your Xcode `Preferences/Account/Detail/`
4. Make sure Signing "Debug" and "Release" aren't empty
5. Close the Xcode(Completely quit from Dock) after you completed those steps
6. Open the Xcode again and do Clean,Build and Install

Hope this help.

Other alternative way,

- Remove the app on the device and re-install
- Change build version no and install again

Comment: "Unplug your iDevices cable at your Mac and plug again." This works for me

Comment: Surprisingly, incrementing the build number worked for me. Weird Xcode behavior.

Comment: The only step I had to take from this solution was to clean the project, then rebuild.

Comment: Ah , had my device in airplane mode.. 

Answer (score 3):

Clean your the project and reattach your device

Answer (score 2):

Do a pod update if you are using CocoaPods. This error can occur due to one of the pod libraries, device logs can be checked for the name of the library.

Comment: I didn't need to do pod update, but `pod install` with a clean worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I get this error only on the second compile for device targets, and I've found that if I just modify one critical source code file by adding just an empty line, the error goes away and Xcode will compile again. The other way is to target a second device which isn't always convenient.
A way around this confusion is to add a an Xcode Run Script that basically does this for you.

## Force Xcode 9 to recompile after a build seems to be file dependent also

touch ${SRCROOT}/MyProject/MySourceFile.swift exit $?
With the above script my issues went away, and I never saw the Xcode Alert again. This bug has been in several iterations of Xcode now.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you have debugged the same app(bundle identifier) with more than one Apple Ids. Remove all accounts from Xcode and sign in to the one which you're currently working with.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too, and also tried all the solution like you. unfortunately, not solve this problem, but I copied my project to another path, the copied one can build on my phone successfully, hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart your Xcode & Uninstall your app.
2. Build & Clean your Project, now it working good.
   this works for me

above is not working please **Restart your system**

Answer (score 0):

This error message occurred when I was building on an iPhone 5 and an iPhone 6 Plus with Xcode 10.  Build in iPhone 5s Simulator gave a different error:  "App could not be installed at this time…/Notification Extension:  No such file or directory"

Problem was resolved by check marking Target Membership in my Notification Extension's source file.

[image: Source file was not a member of the target.]